# Крашится Unity 2018/2020

Tags: c#, unity3d

Крашится Unity 2018/2020
Я новенькая в юнити(
Из сцены GameOver на сцену Level переходит, а при заполнении поля префабами на сцену GameOver не переходит(((
Видео с крашем по ссылке https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H9HiAo6IyfwGqsIA0uk13-a1XzLkyS3Q/view?usp=sharing

Скрипт Game для Grid(поле,сетка);

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Game : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int gridWidth = 10;
    public static int gridHeight = 20;

    public static Transform[,] grid = new Transform[gridWidth,gridHeight];

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        SpawnNextTetromino ();
    }

    public bool CheckIsAboveGrid (tetrismino tetromino) {

        for (int x = 0; x < gridWidth; ++x) {

            foreach (Transform mino in tetromino.transform) {

                Vector2 pos = Round (mino.position);

                if (pos.y > gridHeight -1) {

                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public bool IsFullRowAt (int y) {

        for (int x = 0; x < gridWidth; ++x) {

            if (grid[x, y] == null) {

                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void DeleteMinoAt (int y) {

        for (int x = 0; x < gridWidth; ++x) {

            Destroy (grid[x, y].gameObject);

            grid[x, y] = null;
        }  
    }

    public void MoveRowDown (int y) {

        for (int x = 0; x < gridWidth; ++x) {

            if (grid[x, y] != null) {

                grid[x, y-1] = grid[x, y];

                grid[x, y] = null;

                grid[x, y-1].position += new Vector3(0, -1, 0); 
            }
        }
    }

    public void MoveAllRowDown (int y) {

        for (int i = y; i < gridHeight; ++i) {

            MoveRowDown (i);
        }
    }

    public void DeleteRow () {

        for (int y = 0; y < gridHeight; ++y) {

            if (IsFullRowAt(y)) {

                DeleteMinoAt(y);

                MoveAllRowDown(y + 1);

                --y;
            }
        }
    }

    public void UpdateGrid (tetrismino tetromino) {

        for (int y = 0; y < gridHeight; ++y) {

            for (int x = 0; x < gridWidth; ++x) {

                if (grid[x, y] != null) {

                    if (grid[x,y].parent == tetromino.transform) {

                        grid[x, y] = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (Transform mino in tetromino.transform) {

            Vector2 pos = Round (mino.position);

            if (pos.y < gridHeight) {

                grid[(int)pos.x, (int)pos.y] = mino;
            }
        }
    }

    public Transform GetTransformGridPosition (Vector2 pos) {

        if (pos.y > gridHeight -1) {

            return null;

        } else {

            return grid[(int)pos.x, (int)pos.y];
        }
    }

    public void SpawnNextTetromino () {

        GameObject nextTetromino = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load(GetRandomTetromino(), typeof(GameObject)), new Vector2(5.0f, 20.0f), Quaternion.identity);
    }

    public bool  CheckIsInsideGrid (Vector2 pos) {

        return ((int)pos.x >= 0 && (int)pos.x < gridWidth && (int)pos.y >= 0);
    }

    public Vector2 Round (Vector2 pos) {

        return new Vector2 (Mathf.Round(pos.x), Mathf.Round(pos.y));
    }

    string GetRandomTetromino () {

        int randomTetromino = Random.Range(1, 8);

        string randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/Tetromino_T";

        switch (randomTetromino) {

        case 1:
            randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/Tetromino_T";
            break;
        case 2:
            randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/Tetromino_I";
            break;
        case 3:
            randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/Tetromino_O";
            break;
        case 4:
            randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/Tetromino_J";
            break;
        case 5:
            randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/Tetromino_L";
            break;
        case 6:
            randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/Tetromino_S";
            break;
        case 7:
            randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/Tetromino_Z";
            break;
        }

        return randomTetrominoName;
    }

    public void GameOver () {

        SceneManager.LoadScene ("GameOver");
    }
}
```

Скрипт MenuSystem для кнопки Play Again;

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class MenuSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void PlayAgain () {

        SceneManager.LoadScene ("Level");
    }
}
```

Скрипт TetroMino для префабов;

```
using UnityEngine;

public class tetrismino : MonoBehaviour
{   

    float fall = 0;
    public float fallspeed = 1;

    public bool allowRotation = true;
    public bool limitRotation = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        CheckUserInput ();
    }

    void CheckUserInput () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow)) {

            transform.position += new Vector3(1, 0, 0);

            if (CheckIsValidPosition()) {

                FindObjectOfType<Game>().UpdateGrid(this);

            } else {

                transform.position += new Vector3(-1, 0, 0);
            }

        } else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {

            transform.position += new Vector3(-1, 0, 0);

            if (CheckIsValidPosition()) {

            } else {

                transform.position += new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
            }

        } else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow)) {

            if (allowRotation) {

                if (limitRotation) {

                    if (transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z >= 90) {

                        transform.Rotate(0, 0, -90);
                    } else {
                        transform.Rotate(0, 0, 90);
                    }
                } else {

                    transform.Rotate (0, 0, 90);
                }

                if (CheckIsValidPosition()) {

                    FindObjectOfType<Game>().UpdateGrid(this);

                } else {

                    if (limitRotation) {

                        if (transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z >= 90) {

                            transform.Rotate (0, 0, -90);

                        } else {

                            transform.Rotate (0, 0, 90);
                        }

                    } else {

                        transform.Rotate (0, 0, -90);
                    }
                }
            }

        } else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow) || Time.time - fall >= fallspeed) {

            transform.position += new Vector3(0, -1, 0);

            if (CheckIsValidPosition()) {

                FindObjectOfType<Game>().UpdateGrid(this);

            } else {

                transform.position += new Vector3(0, 1, 0);

                FindObjectOfType<Game>().DeleteRow();

                if (FindObjectOfType<Game>().CheckIsAboveGrid (this)) {

                    FindObjectOfType<Game>().SpawnNextTetromino();
                }

                enabled = false;

                FindObjectOfType<Game>().SpawnNextTetromino();
            }

            fall = Time.time;
        }
    }

    bool CheckIsValidPosition () {

        foreach (Transform mino in transform) {

            Vector2 pos = FindObjectOfType<Game>().Round (mino.position);

            if (FindObjectOfType<Game>().CheckIsInsideGrid (pos) == false) {

                return false;
            }

            if (FindObjectOfType<Game>().GetTransformGridPosition(pos) !=null && FindObjectOfType<Game>().GetTransformGridPosition(pos).parent !=transform) {

                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Скорее всего, это зависание вызвано бесконечным циклом.
 Возможно, бесконечный цикл у Вас в методе **DeleteRow()** : `++y ...--y`

Comment: а что нужно сделать, что бы не было зацикливания?

Comment: Чтобы условие выхода из цикла (y >= gridHeight) когда-нибудь выполнялось